# Paypal API won't load completely on server, but load on localhost

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm having this problem where ther Paypal API is not loading on my server but it loads completely normal on my localhost. I really don't know what and where it went wrong. Everything is the same as I upload files from my localhost to the server, nothing change and it's exactly the same files.

When making a payment using Paypal REST API, I had this error on my server but not on my localhost.

```
Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Api\item' not found in /var/www/test.my-domain.com/public_html/controllers/credits.php on line 24
```

My code as below:

```
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/autoload.php');
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                'hidden-clientid',// ClientID
                'hidden-secret'// ClientSecret
            )
        );

        if (isset($_POST['checkout'])) {
            $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
            $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

            $item = new \PayPal\Api\item();
            $item->setName('Top Up')
                    ->setDescription('My account.')
                    ->setCurrency('USD')
                    ->setQuantity(1)
                    ->setTax(0)
                    ->setPrice(10);

            $itemList = new \PayPal\Api\itemList();
            $itemList->setItems(array($item));

            $details = new \PayPal\Api\details();
            $details->setShipping("0")
                    ->setTax("0")
                    ->setSubtotal(10);

            $amount = new \PayPal\Api\amount();
            $amount->setCurrency("USD")
                   ->setTotal(10)
                   ->setDetails($details);

            $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\transaction();
            $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                ->setItemList($itemList)
                ->setDescription("Top up account")
                ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

            $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
            $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$web_path."credits/done?status=success");
            $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$web_path."credits/done?status=cancel");

            $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
            $payment->setIntent('sale');
            $payment->setPayer($payer);
            $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
            $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

            $response = $payment->create($apiContext);
            $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

            header( "Location: $redirectUrl" );
```

The weird part is that it goes through `$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');` But it does not pass at `$item = new \PayPal\Api\item();`

All code are the same as my localhost and it works on my localhost. The Paypal API is also uploaded on my server on the exact location (/inc/lib/paypal/).

Answer (score 0):

What does the autoload contain. Try and use the full path EX: /var/www/test.my-domain.com/public_html when using the autoload or

Comment: it will load the Paypal API... it's working on my localhost

Comment: I've tried using the full path like you suggested, but it's still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by including the API files one by one.

I include these lines below:

```
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Item.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/ItemList.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Details.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Amount.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Transaction.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/RedirectUrls.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php');
require_once('./inc/lib/paypal/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/PaymentExecution.php');
```

and this fixed the problem. I think this is not really the best solution, but it works. I don't know why I still need to include these one by one where else the autoload.php should have included all these API files altogether.

I hope this helps for others who ran into the same problem like I do.